# How can I use the 'Open With' windows functionality to read the filename that i'm opening into my application?

Tags: vb.net

I have made a basic picture viewer and gif maker using VB. I can use the open file dialogue to open files, but I would like it to be able to be opened by windows while passing the file that I selected into a variable in my application.

I want to be able to click on a picture file and then click 'open with' and have the picture open up in my application.

I have done some research into this and saw that it could be done with the windows registry but I am not too sure how to do this.

I have tried the following which doesn't seem to work

```
If My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count > 0 Then
    Dim FileNameOpenWith As String = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)
    Dim ReaderSystem As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileNameOpenWith)
    picPath = ReaderSystem.ReadToEnd()
    ReaderSystem.Close()
End If
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you :)

Comment: You need to build this into the installer for the application, rather than the application itself.

Comment: What is your actual problem? Adding your application to the "Open With" menu or handling the opened file, when someone actually selected your app in the "open with" menu. If it's the latter, the code above should more or less do the trick, because openwith does basically jsut call your application and passed the file as commandline parameter.

Comment: Also "doesn't seem to work" is not a proper problem description. What have you tried to debug your problem. For instance log out the commandline parameters on startup to see, what parameters your app receives and if they match your expectations.

Comment: If your app is supposed to open image files, why are you using a StreamReader, which is for reading text?

Comment: I think Your `FileNameOpenWith` is supposed to be `picPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this with the below:

```
    If My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count > 0 Then
        Dim FileNameOpenWith As String = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)
        picPath = FileNameOpenWith
    End If
```

Just run this on form load.

Grabs the file location and puts into the picPath variable.

Tested this working.